# Silverlight ComboBox - Tooltip on item subelement

Tags: silverlight, combobox, tooltip

In my Silverlight ComboBox, each item is a horizontal StackPanel with two elements: a small shape and a TextBlock. The shape has a tooltip (using TooltipService). When the dropdown list is open, I can see the tooltip when the mouse cursor is on the shape. However, when the dropdown list is closed, I cannot see the tooltip on the selected item. The only tooltip that I can show would be a tooltip for the whole ComboBox. Is there a way to keep visible the tooltip of the selected item element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by making a user control. A transparent rectangle is placed on top of the ComboBox, with the same size and position as the shape of the selected item. When an item is selected, I copy the tooltip to that transparent rectangle. To the user, it looks as if the tooltip comes from the shape. I also process the mouse click on the transparent rectangle, to open the dropdown list of the ComboBox.